# Struts form and variable declarations

Tags: java, forms, variables, struts

I have a question and I hope somebody can help me out here. Well, I'm developing an application with Struts 1.3.10 and I have a struts form with an object that contains a property. That property is declared as the primitive type `int` and the problem comes when the app shows to the user zeroes(0) instead of nothing when I retrieve that data from the database and turns out to be NULL. Have any of you experienced this problem? How do you guys do to avoid that kind of behaviour?

The only thing it came to my mind was to turn that `int` into a `String` object, but that implies some casting and/or other operations when you have to insert/retrieve/update data into/from the database.

Any help with this?
Thanks in advance,
Carlos

Comment: you need to post some code. This should be fixed in your DAO rather than the front layer. When you retrieve from the Database, check whether or not the value is there. if value is not there then put 0 in your objects property...which will be shown to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I filter in the view and only show to the user numbers that are bigger than 0, that would work in my current project. But what if some of the data is actually 0?

Answer (score 2):

In summary, here's what you want:
If someone has input a value, display the value in the textbox, if someone hasn't entered a value (the value is `null`) display a blank.

Unfortunately there isn't a way that I could find to do this naturally, so you have to do the following:
1. Use an `Integer` on your form for those properties, set these values from the database so that they are null or the actual value.
2. On your jsp you will have to hand craft the input tag like so:

`<c:set var="propertyValue">

  <c:if test="${! empty FORM_NAME.PROPERTY_NAME}>

    <c:out value="${FORM_NAME.PROPERTY_NAME}"/>

  </c:if>

</c:set>

<input type="text" name="PROPERTY_NAME" value='<c:out value="${propertyValue}/>'/>`

Where FORM_NAME is your form's name and PROPERTY_NAME is the name of your `Integer` property.  It's not elegant, but it should work (I haven't tested it though)

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for your answer. Yes, what you said is what I want. And the approach you're talking about is perfect, but I finally set up the property as a String and when I'm going to operate with the database (read or write) I transform the data to what I need (to String to create the model object and to Integer to set and retrieve the data from the database).